# Не сохраняется список последних проектов на ntfs-диске в CodeBlocks (Debian Linux)

Tags: linux, debian, codeblocks

У меня есть Debian Linux, в котором ntfs-раздел смонтирован в поддиректорию домашней директории простого пользователя. На этом разделе у меня находятся проекты CodeBlocks. Монтирование осуществлено через fstab с опциями

```
auto,user,noatime,nosuid,exec
```

При этом, если работать под простым пользователем, после перезагрузки CodeBlocks теряется информация о том, какие последние проекты открывались, а также в какой папке проект создавался в последний раз. Если проект находится на том разделе, куда смонтирован /, либо если работать под суперпользователем, то  всё работает.

Как сделать, чтобы работало?

Comment: Дать простому пользователя соответствующие права.

Comment: А что именно за права нужны? Как это понять?

Comment: от рута ``usermod -a -G adm простой_пользователь`` или ``usermod -a -G root простой_пользователь``

Comment: ничего не произошло. Более того, теперь после закрытия любого проекта CodeBlocks стабильно падает.

Comment: а что должно было произойти по вашему?

Comment: Либо эта команда что-то выведет в консоль, либо уйдёт глюк, который меня беспокоит. Как теперь отменить то, что она сделала?

Comment: а, можно добавить пользователя в группу ``wheel``

Comment: @1stSentinel31YearPerlHist, что вы несёте?! зачем вы даёте рекомендации, которые никакого отношения к вопросу не имеют?

Comment: извините, я пьяный был

Comment: Вот объясните теперь, как это откатить

Comment: Я подобную проблему решал просто: `/home` всё-таки на ext4, но `~/.config/mozilla/firefox` на самом деле **симлинк** на уже виндовый раздел. Работает вполне норм.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При попытке поработать с FLTK я некоторое время провозился с поиском всех недостающих библиотек. В ходе этого было установлено два пакета: `libxfixes-dev` и `libxext-dev`. После этого проблема с CodeBlocks решилась сама собой: он перестал падать при закрытии проекта, а список последних проектов теперь стал сохраняться. Вероятно, мейнтейнеры Debian забыли указать соответствующие зависимости.